# INSERT and UPDATE in one query MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, join, insert, sql-update

I have a simple INSERT query that is run on event click of a button, this gets variables and inserts them into `order` table.

I also would like to UPDATE my `bands` table to reduce the stock by 1 until it reaches 0 then show null or sold out rather than go into negative eg: -6

to know what band is selected I can use :

```
WHERE Band_id = $Band_id");
```

in the same statement.

the current INSERT looks like :

```
"INSERT INTO orders (band_id,user_id,user_name,band_name,band_venue) VALUES('$Band_id', '$user_id', '$user_name', '$name', '$venue')";
```

**Conclusion**

Need to alter my INSERT to also UPDATE WHILE checking that its the current selected band.

**ANSWER PROVIDED CHECK**

this solution has been wonderfully provided and it makes sense but im not quite skilled enough to understand why its not functioning correctly.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (band_id,user_id,user_name,band_name,band_venue) VALUES('$Band_id', '$user_id', '$user_name', '$name', '$venue')";

 $sql_create ="CREATE TRIGGER tg_ai_orders
        AFTER INSERT ON orders
        FOR EACH ROW
          UPDATE bands 
          SET stock = stock - 1
          WHERE band_id = NEW.band_id";

$sql_deleat = "CREATE TRIGGER tg_ad_orders
        AFTER DELETE ON orders
        FOR EACH ROW
         UPDATE bands 
         SET stock = stock + 1
         WHERE band_id = OLD.band_id";

mysql_query ($sql, $sql_deleat, $sql_create, $linkme)
    or die ("could not add to database");
```

Comment: You need a trigger to affect another table in an insert.

Comment: You can use two separate queries and wrap them in a transaction

Comment: Ok fantastic, how would I use a trigger or wrap them in a transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll go with a trigger approach then you'll need two triggers (for insert and delete)

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_ai_orders
AFTER INSERT ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE bands 
     SET stock = stock - 1
   WHERE band_id = NEW.band_id;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_ad_orders
AFTER DELETE ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE bands 
     SET stock = stock + 1
   WHERE band_id = OLD.band_id;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e39c8/1)** demo

Comment: +1 for demo, thank you peterm, I have updated my answer with the answer you provided could you let me know if that's correct? as its not working quite right

Comment: What you're doing is not correct. First of all you have to have triggers created before you issue any insert or delete statements on orders table. Secondly you can execute both `CREATE TRIGGER ...` statements just in mysql command line client since you have to do it only once. Thirdly your `mysql_query()` call is wrong because it accepts only two parameters: a query string and an optional link identifier. If want to create your triggers from php you have to execute each query one at a time.

Comment: Ok, I am a bit confused, but want to know how to do this so il try and implement it.

Comment: What exactly are you confused with? You create triggers **once** the same way you create tables. And then just do your inserts and deletes from your application client code as usual.

Comment: Ok so create triggers in myphpadmin, then insert and delete statement on the php end.

Comment: I apoligies I have not done this before and am having some problems

Comment: No worries. You've got it right. Create triggers in phpMyAdmin once and after that do your inserts and deletes on the php end. To help you with problems you have to be very specific exactly what problems are you faced with?

Comment: the problem is when i try to insert the trigger into my php it tells me #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: am using myphpadmin v 5.5.35

Comment: This error means that you already created a trigger on that table. Again you have to create each trigger **only** and **only once**.

Comment: I am going to look into it a lot more as its working, but im not sure how. one more thing to learn. but thank you