# How to Insert and Update in one query

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I want insert and update data in one query .
C# winform

```
INSERT INTO vehicles (userid,model,price) VALUES (15,365,100000)

UPDATE accounts SET vehicles=365,Money=Money-100000 WHERE id=15
```

It possible ?

Comment: No i don't use ADO.NET , just MysqlConnection

Comment: @BieberKieu You are using ADO.NET, MySqlConnection is an ADO.NET class to access MySql database.

Comment: Refer : [INSERT and UPDATE in one query MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237940/insert-and-update-in-one-query-mysql)

Comment: Should I understand your question as: I want to insert a new record, but if it exists I want to update it? Otherwise what is the reason to set the Money field to 100000 and then update it subtracting 100000. Set it directly to zero.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in one "query"? What is wrong with two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just add both commands in same string separating them with `;`, see the example below:

```
using (var con = new MySqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
    var sqlCommand = con.CreateCommand();
    sqlCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO vehicles (userid,model,price) VALUES (15,365,100000);
                               UPDATE accounts SET vehicles=365,Money=Money-100000 WHERE id=15";

    con.Open();
    var affectedLines = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(affectedLines);
}
```

Affter run it the affectedLines should have value 2.