# How to do insert and update in a single query in mysql

Tags: mysql

This is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE 'jobseeker_text_approval' ( 
    'id' Int( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    'js_id' Int( 11 ) NULL,
    'first_name' VarChar( 200 ) NULL,
    'last_name' VarChar( 200 ) NULL,
    'address_line1' VarChar( 150 ) NULL,
    'address_line2' VarChar( 150 ) NULL,
    'about_me' Text NULL,
    'accomplishments' Text NULL,
    'awards' Text NULL,
    'created_on' Timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY ( 'id' ),
    CONSTRAINT 'js_id' UNIQUE( 'js_id' ) )
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 272;
 )
```

I want to do insert and update in a single query

I have tried this one :

```
INSERT INTO jobseeker_text_approval (created_on)
VALUES('2017-02-26T00:00') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE js_id= 216;
```

But it is adding a new row instead of updating the row if `js_id` exists.
I want to update  the table if there a row with the given js_id . otherwise insert. I also tried the REPLACE INTO function . But it  replace
the given values .But making existing fields  in the row to null.

Comment: This will may help you out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237940/insert-and-update-in-one-query-mysql

Comment: You can create a trigger Before Insert.

Comment: Can I do this without  trigger approach ?

Comment: Include js_id in the insert - look again at how INSERT... UPDATE syntax works

Comment: Yes .I tried .Insert is working .But update is not working